# Need to load side nav bar without using "window.location.reload()" in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I cant able to load the navbar in this method but window.location.reload() is working fine but I don't want to reload the whole application

```
maximizeClick(event) {
    let status = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (status == false) {
      $('body').addClass("nav-function-minify");
      let minandmax = 0;
      var obj = {
        userid: +this.userid,
        minandmax: minandmax
      }
      if (this.userPreferenceStatus) {
        this.commonService.postuserpreference(obj).subscribe(res => {
          this.getuserPreferences();
          this.toastr.success('preference added successfully');
        }, err => {
          this.toastr.error('error in geting ser preferences');
        })
      }
      else {
        this.commonService.UpadateUserPreferences(obj, 'minandmaxupdate').subscribe(res => {
          this.getuserPreferences();
          this.toastr.success('preference updated successfully');
          **window.location.reload();**
        }, err => {
          this.toastr.error('error in geting ser preferences');
        })
      }

    }}
```

Comment: Please Provide your ideas guys

Comment: I may just not know, but can you just remove the Minify class and add the Alternate class, with .removeClass(minify).removeClass(maximize).addClass(maximize) ?

Comment: GALI, in general you should has always your nav-bar. If you want to change some of your nav-bar you can use a service, subscribe to a subject in the nav-bar and emit values from your component: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service (really the title is very bad, the thecnica is used to comunicate two components -it's not necesary a relationship parent-child-. NOTE: to change a class you can use `[ngClass]`:https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass